# How can I configure <List> title from a config file in admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

I need to customize the list title, but to allow it in diff. languages.
I try:

```
<List title='Hi there' ...>
```

and title is changed as expected BUT how do I make the string configurable from a file?

```
<List title={translate('myroot.list.header') ...>
```

doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try with a custom title component:

```
import { translate } from 'admin-on-rest';
const ListTitle = translate(({ translate }) => <span>{translate('my.title')}</span>);

<List title={<ListTitle />} >
```

Comment: thx. it doesn't work as it shows the 'my.title' as text. btw - syntax is wrong so i added ')'  at the end:
const ListTitle = translate(({ translate }) => <span>{translate('my.title')}</span>);

and i don't understand why to use so many 'translate' functions in the statement :-) i don't understand the syntax...

Comment: I have a file like a dic:
export default
{
    resources: {
        posts: {
            name: 'bla',
            },
        },


    },
    my: {
        title: 'tt',
    },

};

which is passed to <Admin> in messages and it works for the Resource Names but not to your suggestion

Comment: Does something print in the console?

Answer (score 0):

hope that it will help you:

customMessages.js

```
export const customMessages = {
    titles: {
        one: 'First Title',
        two: 'Second Title',
    },
}
```

App.js

```
import { englishMessages } from 'admin-on-rest';
import { customMessages } from './customMessages';
const messages = {
    'en': {...englishMessages, ...customMessages},
};
```

resources.js

```
export const ResourceList = (props) => (
  <List {...props} title="titles.one">
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="text" />
      <EditButton />
      <DeleteButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

Replace next to your names:

```
resources.js
ResourceList
```